# Is it possible to have 2 subjects in a defining relative clause?

Tags: relative-clauses, functions

Is it possible to have 2 subjects in a defining relative clause ?
For example:

> **The author *whose book I've read* is going to be in my town**

"whose book" and "I" are 2 subjects here right ? Or "whose book" is describing something ? Can someone explain me ? Thank!

Answer (score 2):

> I've read his book.

Here, "I" is a subject and "his book" is an object.

> The author whose book I've read is going to be in my town.

Same thing.   "I" remains a subject.   "Whose book" remains an object.   That object includes a relative genitive pronoun, which gives us reason to bring that phrase to the beginning of its clause.   It may be fair to call "whose book" the *topic* of the clause, but we have no reason to call it a *subject*.